# How to fix Webhook message delivery failed with error: Microsoft Teams endpoint returned HTTP error 400 in ms teams incoming webhooks

Tags: javascript, webhooks, microsoft-teams

How do I fix the the Webhook message delivery failed with error: Microsoft Teams endpoint returned HTTP error 400.

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "contentUrl": null,
      "content": {
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "msTeams": {
          "width": "full"
        },
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "Container",
            "id": "cd32d5aa-9f98-d6e7-c547-60420f3561d8",
            "padding": "Default",
            "items": [
              {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "id": "9082cad7-6b04-312f-0816-b7d2f06d030e",
                "text": "Carton Creation Failed",
                "wrap": true,
                "weight": "Bolder",
                "size": "Medium",
                "spacing": "Medium"
              },
              {
                "type": "Container",
                "id": "e803d156-374b-8243-1d5c-dc1f36c00e72",
                "padding": "Small",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "FactSet",
                    "id": "6354a598-0946-040f-7dbf-8e4f07cead37",
                    "facts": [
                      {
                        "title": "URL",
                        "value": "/api/pos/multiple"
                      },
                      {
                        "title": "Method",
                        "value": "POST"
                      },
                      {
                        "title": "Payload",
                        "value": "[{....}]" // This array data is more than 300
                      }
                    ],
                    "spacing": "None"
                  }
                ],
                "style": "emphasis"
              },
              {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "id": "9c0b7f9b-2af0-6a47-293f-b8bd1179ecea",
                "text": "Jul 17, 2021 05:55 PM",
                "wrap": true,
                "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                "isSubtle": true,
                "spacing": "Small",
                "size": "Small"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "padding": "None"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The value is an array which is more than 300 and it causing error `Webhook message delivery failed with error: Microsoft Teams endpoint returned HTTP error 400`.
How do I fix on it? but when I try to less the array data to maximum 13 the error doesn't display and it will generate on the teams. but when its more than 14 it causing an error.

here's the data value:

```
[
 {
noFrom: 1,
noTo: 119,
qty: 12,
color: "RED EYE",
customer: "Jake",
date: "2021-08-07",
excess: false,
id: "7vajD0TZ7nFK7nMJ1QKgrB0j_A1UGf2paA",
orNo: "7019124",
mixed: false,
orderQty: 1428,
orderType: "PCS",
packaging: {id: "Z4-NKR3wk7d5ZyCjRfuMJKrR1rxNRuofTg"},
no: "X5125-1",
idNo: "X5125-1-001",
size: "M",
sizes: [{ code: xs, id: 1}],
pack: "CGX-0861-BLUE-XS",
totalQty: 12,
vendor: "eddie",
weight: {id: "uLqsKkyOv7VruJdodZe0nYgSU-B55q0nGA", value: 32},
},{
noFrom: 1,
noTo: 119,
qty: 12,
color: "BLUE EYE",
customer: "Jessie",
date: "2021-08-07",
excess: false,
id: "7vajD0TZ7nFK7nMJ1QXxkajs_A1UGf2paA",
orNo: "7019124",
mixed: false,
orderQty: 1428,
orderType: "PCS",
packaging: {id: "Z4-NKR3wk7d5ZyCjRfuMJKrR1rxNRuofTg"},
no: "X5125-1",
idNo: "X5125-1-001",
season: "2021-09",
size: "M",
sizes: [{ code: m, id: 3}],
pack: "CGX-0861-BLUE-M",
totalQty: 12,
vendor: "James",
weight: {id: "uLqsKkyOv7VruJdodZe0nYgSU-B55q0nGA", value: 32},
},
....
]
```

it success but here's the response Webhook message delivery failed with error: Microsoft Teams endpoint returned HTTP error 400.

Comment: We tried this with postman and this how we added payload value:
`{\"noFrom\": 1,\"noTo\": 119,\"qty\": 12,\"color\": \"RED EYE\",\"customer\": \"Jake\",\"date\": \"2021-08-07\",\"excess\":false,\"id\": \"7vajD0TZ7nFK7nMJ1QKgrB0j_A1UGf2paA\",\"orNo\": \"7019124\",\"mixed\": false,\"orderQty\": 1428,\"orderType\": \"PCS\",\"packaging\": {\"id\": \"Z4-NKR3wk7d5ZyCjRfuMJKrR1rxNRuofTg\"},\"no\": \"X5125-1\",\"idNo\": \"X5125-1-001\",\"size\": \"M\...}` We added more that 13 data in this format and we didn't get any error. Could you please try doing this way?

Comment: Hi @HunaidHanfee-MSFT, i did that & i minified the payload using `jq -r tostring my.json > my.minified.json` & trying with the new minified payload... but still , it's not clear how to troubleshoot the 400 error as there is no verbose log for it.

Comment: The main pb is that Microsoft does not provide detailed error message. So you need to waste some time & you might not find anything at the end.... unless there is documentation about how to get detailed error message.

Answer (score 3):

I just started getting this error. It was working fine until yesterday.

By trial and error eventually I found out that if I removed all occurrences of `"weight": "normal",` from my multiple `TextBlock` the problem was solved.

Like user "Abdennour TOUMI" said, there's no error message and you need to debug it yourself. It happens that all my `TextBlock` had `"normal"` under `"weight"`, so the appearance of the AdaptiveCard remained unchanged.

It would be good if the product gave out useful error messages instead of just  `Webhook message delivery failed with error: Microsoft Teams endpoint returned HTTP error 400 with ContextId 01=2..`

Now I'm worried it will break out of nothing and for no reason again.

Comment: Had the same error message with a similar error source just now. My problem was that the "size" of a text block was declared as "larger" instead of "large". It seems the endpoint is now stricter applying the correct values and doesn't error out gracefully when things are not as expected. The designer at https://adaptivecards.io/designer/ helped me find the issue by showing that this value was not supported.